# O .append() não está funcionando em meu dicionário - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, o meu problema é o seguinte: tenho um dicionário chamado pessoas: `pessoas = {}` que me permite cadastrar o nome e a idade da pessoa. Eu fiz um `input` perguntando quantas pessoas o usuário gostaria de cadastrar: `quantidade = int(input("Quantas pessoas serão cadastradas? "))`.
Após isso ele executa um `for`: `for a in range(0, quantidade):`.
Até ai tudo bem... Eu pergunto o nome e a idade da pessoa a após isso eu faço um `.append()` em meu dicionário e ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Eu realmente não entendi o porque do erro. Alguém sabe explicar?
O código completo:

```
pessoas = {}

quantidade = int(input("Quantas pessoas serão cadastradas? "))

for a in range(0, quantidade):
    nome = input(f"Digite o nome da pessoa {a + 1}: ")
    idade = input(f"Digite a idade de {nome}: ")
    pessoas.append(nome)
    pessoas.append(idade)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dicionários em Python não tem `.append`: eles sempre guardam uma chave e um valor, e isso independe da ordem de inserção - Dada a chave (no caso, o "nome"), ele sempre vai levar o mesmo tempo para te devolver o valor correspondente ("idade"):

```
pessoas = {}

quantidade = int(input("Quantas pessoas serão cadastradas? "))

for a in range(0, quantidade):
    nome = input(f"Digite o nome da pessoa {a + 1}: ")
    idade = input(f"Digite a idade de {nome}: ")
    pessoas[nome] = idade

print(pessoas)
```

Para aprender é importante fazer desse jeito.
Na hora de criar programas mais complexos é importante que um dado que possa ser repetido (o nome), não seja a chave do dicionário: os valores que vem por último vão sobre-escrever os primeiros - mas isso você pega com o tempo  - por exemplo, nesse caso, pode ser melhor ter uma "lista de dicionários", em que cada dicionário tem a chave "nome" e "idade" separados. Mas pra chegar lá, é necessário entender dicionários primeiro.

Answer (score 0):

Da forma que você quer fazer, só usar listas dentro do dicionário, assim vai funcionar :)

```
pessoas = {'Nome': [''],
           'Idade': [0]}

quantidade = int(input("Quantas pessoas serão cadastradas? "))

for a in range(0, quantidade):

nome = input(f"Digite o nome da pessoa {a + 1}: ")
idade = input(f"Digite a idade de {nome}: ")
pessoas['Nome'].append(f'{nome}')
pessoas['Idade'].append(f'{idade}')

print(pessoas)
```